# Error 1009 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference - Mouse Event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have error that came up in the output window in Flash. It says:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at 
    game.fla::MainTimeline/removeAllClips()[game.fla.MainTimeline::frame1:17]
    game.fla::MainTimeline/playWinterLevel()[game.fla.MainTimeline::frame5:55]
```

Here is the piece of code that I think is the culprit:

```
var summerOptionImage:SummerOption = new SummerOption();
summerOption.addChild(summerOptionImage);
summerOptionImage.x=35;
summerOptionImage.y=128;
summerOptionImage.buttonMode = true;
summerOptionImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSummerLevel);

function playSummerLevel(event:MouseEvent){
    gotoAndStop("playSummerLevel");
    removeAllClips();

    stageHolder3.removeChild(introStage2);


}
function playWinterLevel(event:MouseEvent){
    gotoAndStop("playWinterLevel");
    removeAllClips();
    stageHolder3.removeChild(introStage2);
    stageHolder2.removeChild(backgroundStage);
}
```

in the timeline

```
function removeAllClips(){
    while (stageHolder3.numChildren > 0) {
    stageHolder3.removeChildAt(0);
    }
    while (stageHolder2.numChildren > 0) {
    stageHolder2.removeChildAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: For info, SummerOption is the reference class to linkage name in the library.  summerOptionImage is basically a MovieClip instance with linkage name "SummerOption"

Comment: and where is your `removeAllClips` function? problem is there

Comment: @Cherniv, the removeAllClips function is located in the timeline. I have added that function into the code snippet in the description above.

Comment: It looks like the issue is solved by just having  'code' removeChild(stageHolder3) where it points current frame as same as the code resides in...